# flash-video: Jump to point that isn't already loaded?

Tags: html, flash, video, skip

I can't skip/jump to any position in videos before they are completely downloaded.
I don't really have a good example video, but if your internet isn't too fast check this code:

```
  <object width="425" height="300" id="undefined" name="undefined" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"><param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf" /><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" /><param name="flashvars" value='config={"clip":{"url":"http://hdflvplayer.net/hdflvplayer/videos/300_Rise_of_an_Empire.mp4"},"playlist":[{"url":"http://hdflvplayer.net/hdflvplayer/videos/300_Rise_of_an_Empire.mp4"}]}' /></object>
```

Is there any way to make it possible to jump to a position that is not already loaded like you can do it on youtube?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are utilizing a service on the back end that can *stream* the media, I do not think that you can do what you are asking.